Should I make up for this broken fast?
So this Ramadan all days have been successfully fasted but broke it receny accidentally.
I was basically at a restaurant to pick up iftar for later and suggested that they not take so long and have the food ready because I ended up late for what I was going to do because of it.  The owner apologized and while I initially told him that it’s okay, insisted that I sit and have a coffee on them.
Due to aiming to please him, it totally slipped my mind that it wasn’t iftar yet and I took 3 sips before I realized.  I didn’t drink anymore after that and left and ate again at iftar.
I know if you break it accidentally you don’t have to make up for it, but I’m not sure about this one.  Can I get some opinions?
